# Setting up Twilio for a first-timer

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

My current assignment is to set up a callcenter for my internship company to make it possible for them to log calls, see which customers have a project, which don't etc through a customer number that they enter.

right now the company uses VoIPit for their calling (internally and externally) internally the calls come in through their main phone number and are routed to the correct internal employee by the servicedesk. e.g phone 206 for "steve".

I have never done anything related to VoIP so this is all extremely new to me and I am feeling completely lost in the project.

My question basically comes down to how it is possible to setup SIP trunking and if it is possible for all calls to come in through the main number and then being routed to e.g phone 206 internally.

I have looked at the Elastic SIP trunking and from what I could tell is that every employee or phone would have to get their own seperate number instead.

or

as a completely different approach, let all calls during the day be handled by the current solution (VoIPit) and when the office hours ends Twilio kicks in and takes over the calls by routing the incoming calls from the company number to the number bought in Twilio and continue from there.

if someone could point me into the right direction/could explain where to start i would appreciate it a lot and could tell me a bit more about SIP truncing, how to set it up (e.g create an ip access control list/credential list) or how to switch to Twilio completely.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit too broad to give you a meaningful answer, at your current level of understanding you probably need a few hours researching to first understand and then evaluate the different options available to achieve your goal and decide what is best for you.

Basically SIP (Session Initiation Protocol) is a protocol for setting up, modifying and terminating unicast and multicast connections across networks. Calls, conference calls, video calls, all that jazz.

A SIP trunk is a gateway to connect your internal Voip system to the normal telephone system directly via the internet, eliminating the need for physical phone lines to your premises and freeing you from the constraints of only being able to handle as many calls as you have physical phone lines for, as long as you have the bandwidth.

You can set up your internal system to handle calls however you want, so you can have a single incoming number and then route calls using an IVR, you can give everyone their own number etc. It's all down to what you want and how you configure it.